# Windows IIS: Show files in public directory?

Tags: windows, iis

I made a directory called /Files and I want it to show the files when somebody goes to mydomain.com/Files but all I get is permission denied. How can I make the folder show the files when person goes to mydomain.com/Files ? Site is hosted on IIS 6.0 and Win Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can't be hosting a site on IIS 6 under Windows Server 2008 because IIS 6 only installs on Windows Server 2003.

In IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003 just tick the "Directory Browsing" box in the properties for the "Files" directory.

[The procedure for IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(WS.10).aspx) is a bit more involved, but will accomplish the same result.